# how to download source code of cryengine V?

Tags: cryengine

I have heard that cryengine V provides access to the full source code, but I can't find where to download the source code.

Anyone can tell me how to download the source code of cryengine V?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get CryEngine's source code from Github:

1. Download specific revision. For this, visit [CryEngine public repository](https://github.com/CRYTEK-CRYENGINE/CRYENGINE) on Github, find a large green button on the right titled "Clone or download", and in a dropdown menu choose "Download ZIP". It will download a zipped version of the source code for you.
2. Via Git client. For that, install Git from its [official site](https://git-scm.com/). If you already have Git installed, use some Git GUI client to clonse the repository, or create a directory, `cd` to that directory in console/terminal, and run command:

   `git clone https://github.com/CRYTEK-CRYENGINE/CRYENGINE.git`

   This way will also allow you to make pull requests to send fixes back to Crytek if you like.

PS. In order to get SDKs which contains much of the Sandbox content as well as samples, you possibly would also like to download [GameSDK](https://github.com/CRYTEK-CRYENGINE/GameSDK) repository.

PS2. These instructions will let you get the latest version of CryEngine. In order to download specific one, move to `releases` tab on Github website.

Answer (score 0):

There you go: https://www.cryengine.com/get-cryengine

Just register and you get the engine downloader.

Comment: I have registed and download cryengine launcher, also download the engine data (about 1.5G). But i can't find the source code of it, don't know where it is. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: oh, i find it in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Crytek\CRYENGINE Launcher\Crytek\CRYENGINE_5.1\Code\", this is all source code, right?